# Why does this program fail to write the character in the file properly and instead get stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, file-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;

    fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Problem accessing the file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            fseek(fp, -1l, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('_', fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

In this program, I wanted the all the white-space characters in the opened file to be replaced with underscore characters. But this program is behaving in a very unexpected manner and getting stuck in an infinite loop. How do I make it work properly?

I tried to flush the stream `fp` on each iteration of the while loop but still it doesn't give the intended output.

Comment: Please note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. This is rather important when you want to compare its result with the (negative) `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `printf("Problem accessing the file!");` use `perror("sample.txt");` to get the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ch` must be defined with type `int` to accommodate all byte values read by `fgetc()` and the special negative value of the `EOF` macro.

Using `char` makes it impossible to test `EOF` on your platform because type `char` seems to be unsigned, hence the value `EOF` is converted to a positive value `255` when stored into `ch`, which compares different from `EOF` in the test.

Furthermore, you must issue a call to `fseek()` or `rewind()` before switching from reading from the stream to writing to it, which you do, but also to switch back to reading, which you don't.

Finally, you should open the file as binary for `fseek` to operate correctly with absolute numbers such as `-1`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;

    fp = fopen("sample.txt", "rw+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Problem accessing the file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            fseek(fp, -1l, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('_', fp);
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors, but all of them are related to this declaration:

```
...
    char ch;
...
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
...
```

the function `fgetc()` **requires** to use an `int` variable, as it returns the input byte as a number between 0 and 255 (all of them positive) and an extra value (`EOF`, normally defined as -1)  this cannot be handled by a `char`.

The second thing is that, `char` in your computer, is probably defined as `unsigned` so you get in `ch` a number between 0 and 255 (with -1 converted into one of these values by an Undefined Behavior you have incurred in your declaration)

The third thing is that comparing a number in the range (0..255) against -1 makes the left operand to be converted into an integer between 0 and 255, with results in the `while` test to be true always, this makes the `while` loop to run forever.

`fgetc()` is a function that returns 257 values, not 256.  The ones used for all the possible byte values, plus one extra for indicating `EOF` (and this is not a charater, indeed, it is an indicator of what happened in the file, it is a common mistake considering that there's an end of file character, which there's not.